# Reemplazar varios caracteres en una cadena

Tags: javascript

Tengo la cadena *hola soy una prueba* y estoy intentando reemplazar todos los espacios por el caracter _ he utilizado el método ``.replace() pero solo logra cambiar la primera vez que el espacio aparece en la cadena. **¿De que manera puedo hacer que identifique todos los espacios que existen en la cadena (sea cualquier texo) y los reemplace?**

tengo en un javascript lo siguiente:

```
let a = e.target.textContent;
let aux = a.replace(" ","_");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes usar la función `replaceAll()`

```js
let a = 'texto texto texto';
let aux = a.replaceAll(" ","_");
console.log(aux)
```

O el método `replace()` pero usando una expresión regular para buscar los caracteres

```js
let a = 'texto texto texto';
let aux = a.replace(/\s/g,"_");
console.log(aux)
```

Comment: gracias, esta función no me apareció a lo que busque reemplazos en MDN web docs